# SQL Server string constraints

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints

I have a SQL Server database with a time column which can only be filled with the text "am" or "pm" and I'm having trouble finding a constraint that would allow me to do this.

Comment: What flavor of SQL, and can you post more details about the table structure??

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what's your problem. why would you use a text column to store dates?

Comment: Do you mean a time column as per the time datatype or a column to hold the strings am or pm?

Comment: its a column to store the text values am or pm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For SQL server you can use [`CHECK` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which allows you to define a predicate that all the rows must meet in order to enter the table. Like so:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_ampm
CHECK(ColumnName IN ('am', 'pm'));
```